# firebase cloud function expected Promise or value

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function that makes 4 HTTPS requests in it. Every request comes after the previous one is completed in the callback. It basically looks like this

```
request(options, function (err, res, body) {
        request(options, function (err, res, body) {
            request(options, function (err, res, body) {
                return request(options, function (err, res, body) {
```

When I have the **return** in my last request, this gets printed in the Firebase Cloud Functions Console:

> Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value

The function works perfectly but I'm afraid this error would cause issues when this function gets executed more than 10 times a second when the app is in production. I want to get rid of this error. When I return the first request, the error goes away, but the other requests dont work.

How I can return a promise in this scenario?

Comment: It'll be a lot easier if you use the `request-promise` npm module instead of `request`.

Comment: do you think using that would not cause the latter requests to not get called if I return the first promise? @DougStevenson

Comment: Your code will only do what you tell it.  I'm just suggesting that the library will help you navigate promises easier.